# Insert something when *not* before a page break

Tags: page-breaking, conditionals, lua, layout

I've tried to find a solution but obviously the right search phrases escape me ...

I need to insert something into the document which will be suppressed if it would be followed by a page break.

For some context: I'm inserting a list of images and need a graphical separator. But that separator should not be printed at page breaks.
The result should be something like:

```
-----------
| Image 1 |
-----------
=
-----------
| Image 2 |
-----------
---pagebreak---
-----------
| Image 3 |
-----------
=
-----------
| Image 4 |
-----------
```

(with `=` being the visual separator, could be a `\hrule` for example).

If it makes a difference: This is done using Lua, so I can write something with `tex.print()` that will be suppressed by TeX, or if I can detect that state while in Lua (well, AFAICS this is less likely) I could decide what to "print" into the document.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add a MWE with some dummy images and separators?

Comment: I haven't tried *anything* so far because I wasn't able to find anything that looks like conditional insert based on a pagebreak.

Comment: Then just e.g. add some code which always uses the separator. Otherwise everyone who wants to answer has to create a document from scratch just to test their answer. This would most likely lead to less answers.

Comment: Fair point. I'll do so next time.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61627/prevent-action-if-top-of-page/61643#61643

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447806/execute-condition-in-last-environment-typeset-of-its-type/447942#447942

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use leaders, which are discarded at a break, like glue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setbox0\centerline{$\sim$ $\sim$ $\sim$ $\sim$}

\def\sep{%
\par
\bigskip
\cleaders\copy0\vskip\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
\bigskip}

\begin{document}

\centering

\includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image}
\sep
\includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image}
\sep
\includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image}
\sep
\includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image}
\sep
\includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image}
\sep
\includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image}
\sep
\includegraphics[height=.2\textheight]{example-image}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @MarcelKrüger yes 2 was a bit of a kludge anyway, I'll adjust thanks

Comment: @MarcelKrüger updated thanks

Comment: Nice idea. Shouldn't a `\newsavebox` be used instead of `\box0`? I mean, what guarantees that `\box0` won't get modified by the document text, or even by  `\includegraphics` (without any knowledge of its implementation)? I guess the answer is something like “this was a proof of concept and I know by heart everything that `\includegraphics` does, so you can trust me it won't fiddle with your beloved `\box0`”; however, I prefer asking in case I missed something important. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @frougon your assessment is about right:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I see the concept, but I seem unable to find documentation about the use of \cleaders (or \leaders). Even the documentation referenced from https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation doesn't include anything. Only https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/source2e.pdf includes three instances of `\cleaders` in *use*, but these are not more helpful than your solution.

Comment: @uli_1973 it is a tex primitive so the texbook is the main documentation (or I guess the free tex-by-topic book will say something), or search for examples on this site. The usual use of leaders are in horizontal mode to make dots in tables of contents (which is where the name comes from) this vertical mode use is a bit non standard but there are examples around, I'll see if I can see another to link to